# Displaying checkbox list in JSF/PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, checkboxlist, jsf-2.2

I'm displaying checkboxes using `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` as follows.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="colourList" value="#{productColourManagedBean.colours}" layout="grid" columns="4">
    <f:selectItems var="colour" 
                   value="#{productColourManagedBean.colourList}" 
                   itemLabel="#{colour.colourHex}" 
                   itemValue="#{colour.colourId}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

It displays a list of checkboxes in a grid layout based on the list - `List<Colour>` supplied from its corresponding JSF managed bean.

It shows `colourHex` as checkbox label. I need to display the actual colour as checkbox label so that the list can appear something like the following.

[image]

---

This can be achieved by using a container tag like `<div>` something like the following.

```
<div style="background-color:##{colour.colourHex}" 
     title="name : #{colour.colourName} Hex : #{colour.colourHex}">

     &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

But how can this be achieved by using `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `<p:selectManyMenu>` with `var` and `showCheckbox` attributes set. The `var` attribute allows defining custom content by a nested `<p:column>`. The `showCheckbox` attribtue can be set to `true` to get a checkbox column. See also the "advanced" example in [its showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyMenu.jsf).

Here's a kickoff example (with hints how you should actually be naming those properties, there's no need to repeat the entity's name in the property name):

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.selectedColors}" var="color" showCheckbox="true" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableColors}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c.name}" />
    <p:column>  
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background-color:##{color.hex}; border: 1px solid black;" 
            title="Name: #{color.name} Hex: #{color.hex}" />
    </p:column>  
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Bean is rather straightforward:

```
private List<Color> selectedColors;
private List<Color> availableColors;

// ...
```

Here's how it look like for me with 5 basic colors:

[image]